# The replacement of NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveTopLevelObjectWithData(data)

Tags: ios, swift

I currently found out that in our iOS Swift project to set and retrieve objects, the function:

```
NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveTopLevelObjectWithData(data) as? NSMutableArray
```

is depreciated and is recommended by the compiler to use

```
NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchivedObject(ofClass: NSMutableArray.self, from: data)
```

instead. However, `NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchivedObject` always return nil.

Our original `NSMutableArrary`, named `array`, stores our objects, such as,

```swift
public class TestInfo {
    public var name1 = "" 
    public var name2 = ""
    ....
}
```

Those objects were set before by using:

```
NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: array, requiringSecureCoding: false)

set(data, forKey: key)
```

We had tried several different methods such as:

```
NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchivedObject(ofClass: NSMutableData.self, from: data)
```

but all failed with return value nil.

Is there better replacement of `unarchiveTopLevelObjectWithData` to use?

========================================================

Just some answers to the comments (and thanks for the comments)

If we use the following codes to get the error messages:

```
do {

   let obj = try NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchivedObject(ofClass: NSMutableArray.self, from: data)
                
    if obj != nil {
        return obj
    }
} catch {
    print("error: \(error)")
}
```

The error messages are:

***error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4864 "value for key 'NS.objects' was of unexpected class 'Test.TestInfo' (0x1029d4ca0) [/private/var/folders/vk/gjkz3ccx77v2gg880jsmc4780000gn/X/848ED575-5DDA-552B-8779-700AC9EF5015/d/Wrapper/Test.app].
Allowed classes are:
{(
"'NSMutableArray' (0x1e112d6e0) [/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework]"
)}" UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=value for key 'NS.objects' was of unexpected class 'Test.TestInfo' (0x1029d4ca0) [/private/var/folders/vk/gjkz3ccx77v2gg880jsmc4780000gn/X/848ED575-5DDA-552B-8779-700AC9EF5015/d/Wrapper/Test.app].
Allowed classes are:
{(
"'NSMutableArray' (0x1e112d6e0) [/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework]"
)}}***

in the TestInfo.swift we have:

```
import Foundation

public class TestInfo : NSObject, NSCoding, NSSecureCoding {
    public static var supportsSecureCoding: Bool { true }
    
    public var name1 = "";
    public var name2 = "";
    
    public override init() {
        
    }
    
    // MARK: - NSCoding
    public required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        name1 = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "name1") as! String
        name2 = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "name2") as! String
        
    }

    public func encode(with aCoder: NSCoder) {
        aCoder.encode(name1, forKey: "name1")
        aCoder.encode(name2, forKey: "name2")
    }
}
```

Personally, kind of wondering why the Apple wants to depreciate the old clear and neat function and make it so difficult to move from

***NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveTopLevelObjectWithData***

to

***NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchivedObject***

Comment: Are there any error messages in the console? Usually you'll see messages when using `unarchivedObject` and you pass in the wrong class. Certainly passing in `NSMutableData` is wrong. It's an array of other classes. So you need to pass in `NSArray` along with the list of classes the array can hold. And all of the classes you want to archive need to conform to `NSSecureCoding`.

Comment: `unarchivedObject(ofClasses: [NSArray.self, TestInfo.self], from: data)`. The reason of the new API is **`…Secure…`**. And you should not use `NSMutable…` classes and `NSCoding` in Swift at all. Serialize your data to JSON or PropertyList with native Swift APIs and `Codable`.

Comment: PS: `NSMutableArray` is pointless anyway when you assign the object to an immutable constant (`let`). And `obj` is never `nil`. Either it has a value or an error is thrown.

Comment: if NSMutableArray is pointless, what tools should you use if you need to add and remove objects freely? NSArray is not able to do that.

Comment: Swift `Array` aka `[TestInfo]`